# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider cannot be cast to com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProvider

Tags: jsf, jetty

I'm using Primefaces 12.0.0 and Glassfish JSF 2.4.0 dependencies.
Previously I was deploying the war manually in the jetty server 9.4.48 which was running perfectly. Now I had integrated the Jetty in my application, but the webservices are not able to start.
After some research came to know that there shouldn't be multiple JSF jars in the application but there wasn't any duplicate jars present. The configuration is perfect as it is already running in jetty distribution as mentioned above.

I'm getting this error:-

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.4.0 for context '/Reportsportal'
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |Apr 28, 2023 4:51:33 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present. ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider cannot be cast to com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProvider
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext(FactoryFinderInstance.java:293)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.<init>(FactoryFinderInstance.java:147)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at javax.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:140)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at javax.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder(CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:79)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.setFactory(FactoryFinder.java:335)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.setFactory(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:306)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.processFactories(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:250)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:318)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
INFO| jvm 1| 2023/04/28 16:51:33 |at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
```

I started searching and find different approaches:-

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.faces.vendor.GlassFishInjectionProvider</param-value>
</context-param>
```

There is no effect of above context-param. Even I tried to use Jetty InjectionProvider but no use.

Used Weld dependency and its listener and context param but no use:-

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROVIDER_CLASS</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldInjectionProvider</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

None of the changes above worked for me.
my web.xml is as below

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>401</exception-type>
    <location>/Reports.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SSOServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sso</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JsonReportGenerator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/data</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/data/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReportDiscoverer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/discover</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/discover/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>esqblue</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>   

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<session-config>
    ...
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>    
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Based on a [quick search](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.2/com/sun/faces/vendor/WebContainerInjectionProvider.html), `WebContainerInjectionProvider` is an instance of `InjectionProvider`, so this exception can only happen if they're loaded by different classloaders. You will have to debug the function that threw the exception and figure out where these two classes came from.